# How to split string into parts of 5 words by using space as a delimiter

Tags: php, regex, string

For example I have a string:

```
$text = '
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin, erat id cursus consectetur, augue nulla tincidunt lorem, sit amet viverra elit lacus eu ligula. Aliquam pulvinar nibh sed sodales congue. Donec sed magna nibh. Phasellus fermentum malesuada ante eget bibendum. Duis iaculis pellentesque mi, ut ullamcorper mauris congue id. Aenean ac sagittis orci, vel luctus erat. Nunc sapien nisi, porttitor non lorem fermentum, dapibus luctus nibh. Donec imperdiet rhoncus odio quis consequat. Duis ullamcorper malesuada tempus. Quisque vitae urna eu nisi vehicula faucibus. Etiam condimentum mauris ac quam sagittis imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus risus elit, elementum et pulvinar sed, vestibulum non massa. Sed congue sollicitudin suscipit. Proin eleifend enim sapien, quis pharetra sapien imperdiet sed. Proin ligula dolor, scelerisque eu ligula sed, volutpat aliquet erat.

Praesent enim odio, tincidunt id velit quis, imperdiet dictum nisl. Donec pulvinar felis neque, bibendum tincidunt lacus fermentum quis. Sed ante mauris, efficitur et dui quis, porta lacinia dolor. Aliquam tincidunt vitae odio vitae dapibus. Donec lectus nunc, dapibus ut vehicula at, dapibus eu dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tempus porttitor tellus ac interdum. Cras et purus ullamcorper, facilisis ante eget, placerat sem. Cras ornare nunc id tortor aliquam commodo.
'

$explodedData   = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
```

But like this I will split my string into words, using space as a delimiter. Also what Happens if string contains multiple spaces? Will my script be able to split it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `preg_match_all` with the following regex:

```
'~\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,4}~'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK0pH7/1)

This regex will match:

- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+\S+){0,4}` - 0 to 4 sequences (`0` is necessary because there can be a "tail" of less than 5 "words" at the end) of...

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols

[PHP demo:](https://ideone.com/jbvtw7)

```
$re = '~\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,4}~'; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin, erat id cursus consectetur, augue nulla tincidunt lorem, sit amet viverra elit lacus eu ligula. Aliquam pulvinar nibh sed sodales congue. Donec sed magna nibh. Phasellus fermentum malesuada ante eget bibendum. Duis iaculis pellentesque mi, ut ullamcorper mauris congue id. Aenean ac sagittis orci, vel luctus erat. Nunc sapien nisi, porttitor non lorem fermentum, dapibus luctus nibh. Donec imperdiet rhoncus odio quis consequat. Duis ullamcorper malesuada tempus. Quisque vitae urna eu nisi vehicula faucibus. Etiam condimentum mauris ac quam sagittis imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus risus elit, elementum et pulvinar sed, vestibulum non massa. Sed congue sollicitudin suscipit. Proin eleifend enim sapien, quis pharetra sapien imperdiet sed. Proin ligula dolor, scelerisque eu ligula sed, volutpat aliquet erat."; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```